# Use slice(); method to achieve an arithmetic operation

Tags: javascript

My aim is to use a single input to collect numbers and strings then use it to determine a math operation. 
For example, I parse in values such as √64 intending to find the square root of 64. Knowing that this is no valid javascript, so I decided to get the first character with `result[0];` which is "√" and then slice out the remaining values with  `result.slice(1);`  which is "64", then when the condition that  `result[0] == "√"`  is true then  `Math.sqrt(sliceVal)` . This seems perfect and runs well in a mobile editor, but doesn't run in any web browser.

```
function actn() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    var result = input.toString();
    var firstVal = result[0];


    if (firstVal == "√") {
        var sliceVal = result.slice(1);
        display.innerHTML =  Math.sqrt(sliceVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why It is not running at your end but It is working perfectly according to your requirement I tested above code :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function actn() {
    var input = document.getElementById("test").value;
    var result = input.toString();
    var firstVal = result[0];
    if (firstVal == "√") {
        var sliceVal = result.slice(1);
        alert(Math.sqrt(sliceVal));
    }
    alert("No match found");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="test" />
<button type="button" onclick="actn()">Test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okey, I see you've returned the function by default, but I want the user to input a value of their choice.

Answer (score 0):

Checking ASCII value instead of character comparison should work.

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="input" />
      <button type="button" id="sqrRoot">Square Root</button>
      <h1 id="display"></h1>
      <script>
        function actn() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var display = document.getElementById("display");
            var result = input.toString();
            var firstVal = result[0];
            /* Ascii value for √ is 8730 */
            if (firstVal.charCodeAt(0) === 8730) {
                var sliceVal = result.slice(1);
                display.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(sliceVal);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("sqrRoot").addEventListener("click", function () {
            actn();
        });
    </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Yes, The ASCII value check does the job as intended. It's a lot clearer now that the use  of ASCII values is an efficient  way of comparing symbols